# Where did the Programmers Stack Exchange site go?

Tags: discussion, support

Wasn't there a Programmers Stack Exchange site? A site different from Stack Overflow, of course. I don't see it listed.

Comment: Nope @RaisingAgent that is an entirely different site and not what the Programmers SE used to be.

Comment: the question I had on "programming" or whatever it was called was migrated to software engineering.  So, kinda, yeah.

Comment: @Thufir not really. Nothing was migrated, the site simply changed its name.

Comment: heh, I *think* that I meant migration in the normal usage, not specific to SE.  however, fair enough!

Comment: They're hiding from you.